# Cannot delete DC from AD after dcpromo /forceremoval

Tags: windows-server-2008, metadata

Very much a follow on from this question I asked earlier [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/327826/server-2008-dc-rejecting-replication-requests).  Trying to go through metadata cleanup but every time I click delete on the offending DC I get an access denied (after prompts about it being a GC).  Is there any other way I can remove it?  I have unchecked the "protect from accidental deletion" option on the OU Domain Controllers, added myself as an Enterprise Admin (was already a Domain Admin) and generally thrown my toys out of the cot.  Have I missed a glaringly obvious step somewhere?  I thought the first process of metadata cleanup was removing the account and then a case of tidying up DNS and NTDS bits that pointed to the DC.

EDIT:  So looking at NTDS Quotas OU thorugh ADSIEdit I notice that someone has added Everyone - Deny Special Permissions - Delete and Delete Subtree.  Is this a normal setting to have configured?

EDIT2:  Oh wait it gets better.  Everyone has been assigned Deny permissions (to all sorts of attributes) to delete from teh Domain Controllers OU.  I am guessing this is not a normal security practice for AD?

Comment: Inspect the ACL on the Domain Controller object and post it here. It's possible that someone removed the `Enterprise Admin/Full Control` ACE from the ACL.

Comment: Looking at the Security tab for both the OU and the computer object I can see Enterprise Admins listed as having full control.  I have also toggled the protect from deletion on the object and OU in case it was a corrupt attribute.  tried from three different DCs.  driving me nuts :)

Comment: @MarkM thanks for the pointer to ACLs.  As above in EDIT2 someone has denied Everyone access to certain abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ACL on the domain controller object and make sure that Domain Administrators and Enterprise Administrators have the appropriate `Full Control` ACE. Also check to make sure that there isn't any weird deny ACEs.