# LSASS - Directory Services could not start - 0xc000006a

Tags: service, directory, lsass

**LSASS - Directory Services could not start - 0xc000006a**

This is the error message I am getting after restoring an old registry backup. I read somewhere that this has to do with the backup being more than 180 days old, but how would I go about repairing this if I do not have a backup less than 180 days old?

Answer (score 3):

This is most probably on a domain controller right? the tombstone time has expired. Build the DC from scratch

Answer (score 1):

0xc000006a means the username or password is incorrect.  Since this is a computer account, this usually means that the password is incorrect.

**How to use Netdom.exe to reset machine account passwords of a Windows Server domain controller**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325850

FYI - restoring old domain controller backups can have several unwanted side effects.  One is referred to as "lingering objects".  This is when an object that was removed is re-introduced into the replica from a domain controller that did not receive the removal replication.

See the following for detailed information on dealing with lingering objects.

[Server 2008 DC rejecting replication requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/327826/server-2008-dc-rejecting-replication-requests/328137#328137)